# KSP throttle off after set time

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Is there a way I can automatically turn off a burn after a pre-set countdown?
For example, I have a 2 hour burn to do, so I want to start the burn, then leave it to do it's thing and automatically throttle down after the 2 hours without me needed to be at my computer.
Alternatively, I would like the throttle to automatically switch off when the maneuver gets to it's "green tick" zone.

Comment: Generally, asking for mods that do certain things are seen as recommendations, and off-topic. Better to just ask how to do it. Answers can still recommend mods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [MechJeb](https://mods.curse.com/ksp-mods/kerbal/220221-mechjeb) for this extensively. Once I was able to "master" the launching and orbit, and it started to become tedious, MechJeb did an extremely efficient job of getting into orbit and performing orbital transfers.

One thing of note, if you're playing on Career mode, the MechJeb parts that allow this functionality need to be unlocked via the science tree. (If you would otherwise feel guilt about using a mod for this, having to earn it may alleviate said guilt.) :)

Comment: MJ also helps a lot when you're deploying Kerbol-synchronous satellites for the LOS communications mods.